# Setting event handler for each Raphael object

Tags: jquery, raphael

I have a simple script that is creating several Raphael objects from an array and then assigning event handlers to each.  Problem is that only the last event handler is executing for all objects.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
var blockDiagram = {
    "block" :[
     {
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100,
        "text" : "this is block 1",
        "cx": 10,
        "cy": 10,
        "fill" : "blue"
     },
     {
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100,
        "text" : "this is block 2",
        "cx": 120,
        "cy": 10,
        "fill" : "yellow" 
     },
     {
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100,
        "text" : "this is block 3",
        "cx": 230,
        "cy": 10,
        "fill" : "red" 
     }
    ]
 };

var paper = new Raphael("holder", 700, 700)

for ( i=0;  i< blockDiagram.block.length; i++)
{
     ms = 500;
    width = blockDiagram.block[i].width;
    height = blockDiagram.block[i].height;
    text = blockDiagram.block[i].text;
    cx = blockDiagram.block[i].cx;
    cy = blockDiagram.block[i].cy;
    fill = blockDiagram.block[i].fill;
    p = paper.rect(cx,cy, width, height).attr({"fill": fill});
    txt = paper.text(cx ,cy, text).attr({fill: 'black', stroke: "none", opacity: 0, "font-size": 15});
    p.mouseover(function () {               
            txt.stop().animate({opacity: 1}, ms);
        }).mouseout(function () {
            txt.stop().animate({opacity: 0}, ms);
        });

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make element lists with [`Paper.set()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.set)

```
var set = paper.set();

for(var i = 0; i< blockDiagram.block.length; i++) {
  var width = blockDiagram.block[i].width,
    height = blockDiagram.block[i].height,
    text = blockDiagram.block[i].text,
    cx = blockDiagram.block[i].cx,
    cy = blockDiagram.block[i].cy,
    fill = blockDiagram.block[i].fill;

  var p = paper.rect(cx,cy, width, height).attr({
    block: blockDiagram.block[i], // here the custom attribute gets set (block object)
    fill: fill
  });
  set.push(p);
}
```

What I added as attribute `block` is a custom attributes created with[`Paper.customAttributes`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.customAttributes).  So you can attach information to any element.

That's how I created the `block` attribute:

```
paper.customAttributes.block = function(block) {
  return {
    block: block
  };
};
```

So when calling the attribute with parameter it will be set otherwise it returns the value set before

Now, the best part, we can attach handlers to an entire set and get the information set in the extra attribute!

```
var txt;
set.mouseover(function (e) {
  var block = this.attr('block'); // getting the attribute (the block object with the data)

  txt = paper.text(block.cx ,block.cy, block.text).attr({fill: "black", stroke: "none", opacity: 0, "font-size": 15});
  txt.stop().animate({opacity: 1}, ms);
}).mouseout(function (e) {
    txt.stop().animate({opacity: 0}, ms);
});
```

I made a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Y4kw/) for you to check it out. Of course it can be improved but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Wel that certainly works thank you.  I was playing with sets and trying to make that work but had no success.

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution based on [this](http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html) example.  For anyone else who might be interested.

```
var blockDiagram = {
    "block" :[
     {
        "width": 100,
        "height": 200,
        "text" : "this is block 1",
        "cx": 10,
        "cy": 10,
        "fill" : "blue"
     },
     {
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100,
        "text" : "this is block 2",
        "cx": 120,
        "cy": 10,
        "fill" : "yellow" 
     },
     {
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100,
        "text" : "this is block 3",
        "cx": 230,
        "cy": 10,
        "fill" : "red" 
     }
    ]
 };


Raphael.fn.BlockDiagram = function (blockDiagram) {
var paper = this,      
    Blocks = this.set();

function square(cx, cy, width, height, params) {       
    return paper.rect(cx, cy, width,height).attr(params);
 }

var process = function (i) {
        var width = blockDiagram.block[i].width,
            height = blockDiagram.block[i].height,
            text = blockDiagram.block[i].text,
            cx = blockDiagram.block[i].cx,
            cy = blockDiagram.block[i].cy,
            fill = blockDiagram.block[i].fill,               
            ms = 500,                
            p = square(cx, cy, width, height,{fill: fill}),
            txt = paper.text(cx , cy, text).attr({fill: fill, stroke: "none", opacity: 0, "font-size": 20});
        p.mouseover(function () {
            p.stop().animate({transform: "s1.1 1.1 " + cx + " " + cy}, ms, "gradient");
            txt.stop().animate({opacity: 1}, ms, "gradient");
        }).mouseout(function () {
            p.stop().animate({transform: ""}, ms, "gradient");
            txt.stop().animate({opacity: 0}, ms);
        });
        Blocks.push(p);
        Blocks.push(txt);
    };

for (i = 0; i < blockDiagram.block.length; i++) {
    process(i);
}
return Blocks;
};

$(function () { 
Raphael("holder", 500, 500).BlockDiagram(blockDiagram);
});
```